# What is the difference between developer.apple.com and iTunes Connect?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, developer-program

The two sites seem to be related, but I don't understand the conceptual difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/) is the developer portal with access to documentation, videos, tools etc. required to develop software for macOS, iOS, watchOS etc.
- [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) is the entry portal to the App Store used to manage content on the iTunes Store and Apple Books.

Comment: Short form They are not related. You can have  different logins to each of tthem

Comment: So would you say that developer.apple.com is for the actual development, whereas iTunes Connect is for distribution?

Comment: @RNdev Not sure what your actual question here is, somehow. developer.apple.com is the developer *library*, development is done locally (Xcode or whatever). iTunes Connect is required if you want to distribute through the App Store, you don't need it if you distribute macOS software directly.